# Php code for is not in array

Tags: php

I need a little bit of help, being a newb with php.

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && $currentpage IS NOT 1,2,3.....100){
}
```

How can I write this corectly?
Maybe put the numbers inside an array?

Ty

Comment: So `$currentpage` will be a single number?

Comment: Looks like `$currentpage` is a page id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && !in_array($currentpage, range(1, 100))
```

Or:

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && ($currentpage < 1 || $currentpage > 100))
```

Comment: This is a nice solution if `1, 2, 3, ... 100` was actually what he was going for... I just assumed that the data was not always necessarily a range.

Answer (score 2):

Use `!` and `in_array()`

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3... , 100);

if($catname != 'used-cars' && !in_array($currentpage, $array)){

}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && !in_array($currentPage, array(1, 2, 3, ..., 100)))
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want all numbers withing the range of 1-100, you can use `in_array()` and `range()` like so:

```
if (($catname != "used-cars") && (!in_array($currentPage, range(1,100))) {
   //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this might work?

```
if($catname != 'used-cars' && $currentpage > 100)
{
    //Code here
}
```